# Iptables Issue can't SSH Remote Machines

Tags: iptables, ufw

I want to SSH to **192.168.1.15** Server from my machine, my ip was **192.168.1.99**

Source Destination was UP, with IP **192.168.1.15**.

This is LAN Network there are 30 Machine's Connected to the network and working fine, I'm Playing around the local machine's cos i need to apply the same rules in Production VPS

I have applied the below iptables in my machine 192.168.1.99, Now i can't receive any packets from Outside and i can't send any packets Outside, While applying the Below Chain

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

After the above CHAIN i have added the Below rules and it want to allow ssh from machine to **192.168.1.15** to access the **192.164.1.15** but still i can't access **192.168.1.15**

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -o eth0 --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Any one Please Check Weather my Rules are Wrigt. Still i can't access the machine 15

Answer (score 1):

The rules for iptables are applied in order and the *first matching rule* is applied. You therefore need to insert the rules to allow traffic *before* the rules that drop all traffic.

Comment: Solved by replacing the eth0 to br0, cos in my desktop there is bridge so i have to replace it with br0